# How to make read JSON to client using angular2

Tags: angular

I have a data, I must read that data to html and display the values.
I have tried with approach of calling JSON via API, but not able to do. Please have a look at demo of my code.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzq8uc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Is there any approach, where we can use this data without API calling, I have used JSON file because I don't want this file to be lengthy.

HTML:

```
 <div>
    <select >
            <option value=''>select</option>
            <option *ngFor="let country of countryList" [value]="country.dial_code">{{country.name | slice:0:20 }}
              {{country.dial_code}}</option>
          </select>
          <div>
```

Comment: Don't use the deprecated Http service. Use the documented HttpClient. https://angular.io/guide/http. And put your JSON in a place where the server will serve it, as is. With the Angular CLI, that means under assets. But if you're OK with this being part of the application itself, then you can just put in in the TypeScript sources directly. Yes, that TypeScript file will be long. So what?

Comment: Did u get my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also import all data from .json file:

```
import * as data from './file.json';
```

And use it then as `data` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
export class AppComponent  {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.getCountryList().subscribe(data => {
            this.countryList=data;
        });
    }

    public getCountryList():Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("./assets/countrylist.json")
    }

}
```

- Should change `Http` by `HttpClient`.
- Your JSON file should be inside `assets` folder.

---

**How to change `Http` by `HttpClient` ?**

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Instead of :

```
 import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

And :

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Instead of:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to make ajax calls if you are including data with application. Just import it from json file and expose

```
import allCountries from './countrylist.json'
```

and then your list is accessivle as `allCountries`

```
  constructor(private http: Http
  ) {
    this.countryList=allCountries;
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-45uaxp